# Elasticsearch boost documents where fulltext query substring exactly matches field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 8.6 and I'm trying to boost documents in a full-text search where the value of a field is exactly contained within the query text. In other words, where a field is an exact substring of the query.

For example, say I have these documents:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Kids t-shirts",
  "category": "Kids clothes"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "All about kids",
  "category": ""
}
```

Let's say I search for `kids` based on the `title` field, and the docs are returned in the order #2, #1. That's good so far!

Here's where I'm stuck:

If the query ***contains*** the exact name of a `category` - for example, `blue kids clothes`, I'd like to boost the document where the category matches the query - in this case, #1.

I've tried boosting with an extra `match` or `match_phrase` query on the `category` field but it works the wrong way around. For example, now searching for `kids` will also trigger the boost for document #1 because the match score between `kids` and the category `kids clothes` is positive.

An exact match doesn't work for the same reason - it's the wrong way around. I want `blue kids clothes` to trigger the boost based on the category `kids clothes` being an exact substring of the query, but an exact match would only boost if the query was exactly `kids clothes`.

To clarify, here are some cases where I want the boost to trigger:

| Query text | Should boost doc #1? |
| --- | --- |
| kids clothes | **Yes** (exact category matches query) |
| blue kids clothes | **Yes** (exact category is contained within query) |
| kids | **No** (no exact match) |
| clothes for kids | **No** (both words from category are in query but wrong order = no exact match) |

(Doc #2 should never be boosted because its `category` field is empty)

Any advice or direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: By adding an additional clause you will always have a boost in the score if there is a match between the tokens.
In your example, kids toys will boost because kids is a token from document 1.
In fact, I don't see any problem, you want to do something that I don't see any sense since there is similarity.
I don't know why you don't want to apply boost in certain situations, is it a business rule?

Comment: @rabbitbr sort of! My `kids toys` example was confusing, so I'll replace it with `kids`. Imagine our website has lots of different types of content, not just about clothing. Some users search for generic things like `kids`, where we'd like the `All about kids` page to rank highly (and that page has nothing to do with clothes). However, lots of our users know the exact category they're looking for, like `kids clothes`, and include it in their query. Those are the queries we want to boost. Maybe a better way to describe it is like 'automatic filtering' - but boosting rather than filtering?

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to do this was with a custom `script_score`:

```json
{
  "script_score": {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "category": "blue kids clothes"
      }
    },
    "script": {
      "source": "params.query.contains(doc['category.keyword'].value) ? 1.0 : 0.0",
      "params": {
        "query": "blue kids clothes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Happy to hear any other answers!